# Is it bad to create orderers in the same organizations with peers in hyperledger fabric?

Tags: hyperledger-fabric

In most examples I noticed that a separate organization is created for the orderers. I was wondering if putting them in the same organization as peers is some kind of an antipattern? Are there any downsides to this approach? Or what is the benefit of separating them?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Even if the orderers and peers are run by the same logical entity, it is a good pattern to put them in different organization MSPs, as this will provide more flexibility (permissions, revocations, future changes, etc).